# iptables how to port forward remote to local

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

This is the scenario:

I have an encoded file that I cannot change the API URL but I know what it is. Let's suppose it is `https://my.api.site.com/v1`.

When I run `php myfile.php`, it connects to the API URL, but the issue is recently it cannot connect due to some network issues in my areas.

So I have to run a socks proxy and then connect via socks.

This is what I do in my local server: `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9999:my.api.site.com:443 root@remote`, and then add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 my.api.site.com
```

I want to do this:

> Whenever I run `curl -L https://my.api.site.com/v1`, it should go through the `https://my.api.site.com:9999/v1`.

Since file is encoded, I cannot change the URL.

How can I do this via firewalls like `iptables` or `csf`.

The OS is Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Can you check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/28170005/22981715 is similar to what you want?

Comment: @NomeEoleSem thanks, but no, it's not.

Comment: @Saeed wju does that Stackoverflow link not work for you?

Comment: @davidgo I tried that, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -t nat -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:9999
```

This will intercept traffic destined for locahost on port 443 and NAT it to port 9999.   You do not need to use a SOX proxy - all you need to do is intercept traffic destined for port 443 on the local machine and rewrite it so it goes to port 9999 instead.    (The domain still needs to resolve to localhost, so you likely still need the hosts file entry)

Comment: But how does it understand which domain to do? Because of `hosts` file?

Comment: I dont understand the question. The hosts file entry gets the request to go to the the loopback address on the local machine. The http(s) protocols specifyvthe domain name as part of the protocol.

Comment: I know it's not very clear. I mean how does `--dport 443` understands that it should forward `my.api.site.com` which is listed in `/etc/hosts` and not forward `google.com` which is not listed? Your answer worked for me as expected and everything works fine.

Comment: Ah. The bit "-o lo" instructs the iptables rule to only look for traffic going through the loopback interfsce.  It should be "good enough" for testing purposes, but you may want to match the dst ip more specifically as well in the unlikely event you have more then just 127.0.0.1 associated with the lo interface.